# auto calculate field value in sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, sonata-admin

I use symfony + sonataAdminBundle for my application and 
I have an entity "Produit" with 2 inputs "PrixAchat" and "PrixVenteTTC" and another field called "marge" that I like Calculated his value in with a formula with the other input, this is why I have create an disabled input for this field :

**ProduitAdmin**

```
 protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
  {
    $formMapper
        ->add('prixAchat')
        ->add('prixVenteTTC')

        ->add('marge',null,array(
        'label' => 'Marge',
        'read_only' => true,
        'disabled'  => true,
        'attr' =>array(
        'template' => 'CRUD/marge.html.twig',
        )))
   }
```

**Template: Marge.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}



{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(function(){


     var prixVente = document.getElementById('form [id$="_prixVenteTTC"]').value;
    var prixAchat = document.getElementById('form [id$="_prixAchat"]').value; 

    document.getElementById('form [id$="_marge"]').value = ((prixVente/prixAchat)*100)-100;

    }); 



 </script>
 {% endblock %}
```

But the value is not calculed .. 
Somewone have an idea and can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

That code only runs once. You should add a change listener to the input fields that triggers recalculating the price

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/ if you use jquery. or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172963/jquery-change-method-in-vanilla-javascript to use just plain Js