# HTML, updating field when dropdown item is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am fairly new to HTML. I am working on an event website, the website requires people to register for events, on the website is a dropdown showing the events currently running, a user can choose an event from the dropdown, when they choose the event from the dropdown, I would like the site to update a field named `eventDescription` with the event's description. Here is my `HTML code`

```
<div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <select name="event" required="true" class="form-control" style='width:100%'>
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select the event you registering for</option>
                                <?php foreach ($events as $event) {?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo  $event['id']; ?>"> <?php echo  $event['title']; ?></option>
                                  <?php } ?>
                          </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <a class="form-control" id="eventDescription" placeholder="Selected event description"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I am new to HTML I have no idea on how to do this, although I know I can do it with `javascript` how do I update id="eventDescription" with `$event['description']` ?

Comment: Since your post has a tag of just javascript you can use this SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) to learn how to send an asynchronous request to your server and return the value you want to place inside your element with id = "eventDescription" and this SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172963/jquery-change-method-in-vanilla-javascript) to learn how to attach a change event to your drop down which in turn would use the asynchronous call to the server to get the value for the selected option

Answer (score 0):

You can have any attribute that you want even if that is not a known attribute. For example, you can have `description`:

```
<option value="<?php echo $event['id']; ?> description="<?php echo $event['description']; ?>"> <?php echo $event['title']; ?></option>
```

Now, when you do javascript on the change event of the `select` tag, retrieve the info from the selected `option` by accessing its attribute named `description.

Comment: Thanks but like I said am new to HTML and Javascript, I know I can do it but not sure how