# Converting jQuery .change() to plain JavaScript/DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing an autofill extension. I want to fill an input field with a value, example value = "12345", and then trigger the equivalent of a jQuery $(element).change(), but in pure JavaScript/DOM.

I've tried dispatching the change method,

```js
document.querySelector("input[name=inputIWantToChange]").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

but the behavior is different than that of

```js
$("[name=inputIWantToChange]").change()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery change method in vanilla JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172963/jquery-change-method-in-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: @EternalHour That question is about attaching the event handler; this question is about dispatching (triggering) the event handler.

Comment: "the behavior is different"; well, sure. jQuery does something different from the native DOM. That's kind of the point of jQuery. :). What is different and why is it a problem?

Comment: Well in that case, this should cover it. [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) or this [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually). Plenty to choose from on this topic.

Comment: @EternalHour Agree wholeheartedly. Except those basically answer with code the OP already has, so I'd like to hear what their actual problem is, since apparently they are having a problem with it. Hard to tell what, without a response after a dozen minutes...

Answer (score 1):

[Looking at jQuery's source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deprecated/event.js#L40), it would appear that jQuery works by invoking the handler that you have bound to the event (with a fake event that it creates) when you call `change()` - which means that you're going to have to find a way to be able to invoke a function, and also have the event invoke the same function. Consider the following:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector("input[name=inputIWantToChange]");

elem.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    onElemChange() // Pass data from the event `evt` here, as needed
});

function onElemChange() {
    // Your handler method here
}
```

When you'd want to invoke a "change event" as you do with jQuery, you can then just call `onElemChange` with the information you'd have gotten from the event, assuming you'd want to use any of the information from the event.